# Как вручную очистить память из под управляемого кода в c#

Tags: c#, .net

С помощью оператора new создаются управляемые объекты, которые после завершения работы приложения очищаются сборщиком мусора, можно ли до завершения работы приложения вручную очистить из под него память, например, после его создания, присвоить null и очистить?

Comment: На самом деле ответ в вашем вопросе.

Comment: Как только в коде не остаётся ссылок на объект (например, кончился блок кода, где он используется), объект может быть удалён сборщиком мусора. Но нет гарантии - когда именно он будет вызван. Можно вызывать сборщик мусора вручную через `GC.Collect()`. А так да, если вы не хотите выходить из блока кода, то присвоив `null` той переменной, которая хранила ссылку на объект, вы делаете так, что ссылок на него больше нет и сборщик мусора имеет право его удалить. Но обычно это делается как-то по-другому (например, созданием локальной переменной в методе) и нет нужды специально присваивать `null`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На примере `MediaElement:`

```
MediaElement me = new MediaElement();


        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            me = null; // он испарился....
        }
```